# Is there a more functional way to transform an Option value of None?

Tags: scala, option-type

I have an Option[Int] and I want to transform None to Some(0).

I know I can do this with pattern matching. Is there anything more direct or simple?

thanks

Comment: `opt orElse Some(0)` - also, make sure you want to maintain the `Option` otherwise it may be better to just use `getOrElse` or `fold`

Answer (score 0):

Answered in the first comment.

What I was looking for was the orElse function.
I think my mind skipped over it thinking of getOrElse.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend: `Some(x.getOrElse(0))`